# Allow Access-Control-Allow-Origin for a Flutter app in Firebase hosting

Tags: flutter, cors, firebase-hosting

I've been researching for hours how to allow CORS in Firebase hosting for my [flutter app](https://github.com/tomasbaran/ambee2_track_progress) and having `firebase.json` this way is the only solution I have found to be working. Question is, is it safe to do it this way in terms of security?

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "headers": [ {
        "source": "*",
            "headers": [ {
                "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                "value": "*"
    } ]
  } ],
    "public": "build/web",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

I only thought it was working, for some reasons it looked it was working but not any more... This is the error I'm getting in the Google Chrome console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.mailerlite.com/api/v2/groups/105183683/subscribers' from origin 'https://test-47a07.web.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
main.dart.js:2909 XMLHttpRequest error.
```

Basically what I'm doing is posting via RESTful API. Here is part of my app that does it:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:ambee2_track_progress/sensitive.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class MailerLiteApi {
  String _url = 'https://api.mailerlite.com/api/v2/groups/105183683/subscribers';
  Map<String, String> _headers = {'X-MailerLite-ApiKey': Sensitive.mailerLiteApiKey};

  addSubscriber(String email) async {
    if (email == null) throw 'Error #0: Empty email';
    Map<String, String> _body = {"email": email};

    http.Response response = await http.post(_url, headers: _headers, body: _body);
    print(response.statusCode);
    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      dynamic errorMsg = jsonDecode(response.body);
      errorMsg = errorMsg['error']['message'] + ': ' + email;
      //print("memem: $errorMsg");
      throw 'Error #1: $errorMsg; status code: ${response.statusCode}';
    }
    print(response.body);
  }
}
```

Comment: CORS headers need to be applied to the server the requests are going TO. If you are making a request to `https://api.mailerlite.com`, that is the response that needs the CORS headers.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and searching for a solution for hours now. Can you please tell how did you made it work? I'm using Firebase Hosting (not cloud)

Comment: It was a year ago but if I remember correctly, I was NOT able to solve this so I was forced to create my own backend — not hosted on firebase.